# Can't read in pom.xml file from webapp

Tags: java, spring, maven

So my tomcat webapps directory looks like this:

```
C:/tomcat/webapps/myApp/
myApp/
    resources/...
META-INF/
    MANIFEST.MF
    maven/
        my.package.name/
            myApp/
                pom.properties
                pom.xml
WEB-INF/
    classes/...
    lib/...
    web.xml
```

I have an AppConfig.java (java spring config) where I am trying to get the pom.xml file so I can get certain things out of it. I have tried many things but have been unsuccessful in getting the file. I have a bean that I have just been putting a breakpoint in and trying different things to get the file.

```
@Bean
    public String clientVersion()
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/pom.xml")));

        return "";
    }
```

I have tried `ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream()` with many different paths though from what I have been able to find in other posts and forums `ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("META-INF/maven/my.package.name/myApp/pom.xml")` should work, but I get null no matter what I do. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this out - META-INF/maven/my/packagename/myApp/pom.xml. Please remove the dots and front forward slash in your dir name

Answer (score 0):

To load resource you have to provide full path not only filename. Eg `/maven/mypackage/myapp/pom.xml`
Try with opening stash.

Comment: I tried the suggestion, it didnt work. I read in another SO that the ClassLoader doesn't care about the leading slash. I couldn't find where I saw that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to:

```
@Bean
public String clientVersion()
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/maven/my.package.name/myApp/pom.xml")));

    return "";
}
```

Depending on how it's stored on you file system, the `my.package.name` might need to actually be `my/package/name`.

Comment: the actual directory name is with dots, not slashes but I tried anyway and it didnt work.

Comment: maybe thats the problem ?

Comment: But, first, try removing the dots and replacing the package name with proper subdirs.

Comment: @Antoniossss I dont think thats a problem because my.package.name is actually the groupId for the maven artifact.

Comment: @carlspring I don't understand what you are asking "Try putting /META-INF/** under /WEB-INF/classes"

Comment: Just move the `META-INF` directory under `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: I understand bout maven artifact but how about classloader?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `ClassLoader` class, because you're probably picking up the wrong classloader (confusing, right?!).
Instead use `my.package.name.MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/maven/my.package.name/myApp/pom.xml")));`, this way you can ensure both files (the class and the pom.xml) are available with the same classloader, since the are in the same archive.

Answer (score 0):

I do this to get it as a String (inside a class called ServerResource.java, so swap in your class name):

```
InputStream is = ServerResource.class.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/maven/org.buffalo/platform/pom.xml");
String pom = getStringFromInputStream(is);
```

if you extract your war/jar, you can confirm the path to the pom (for me it's META-INF/maven/org.buffalo/platform_ws/pom.xml)

Answer (score 0):

[`Class::getResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) loads resources from the classpath; in a web application, that means files inside WEB-INF/classes, or inside one of the JAR files inside WEB-INF/lib. Your POM file isn't in either of those places, so it's not on the classpath.

Rather, being somewhere under the WAR root, it's a web resource, rather than a classpath resource. You can load web resources using [`ServletContext::getResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-).

Your code should look like:

```
@Bean
public String clientVersion(ServletContext servletContext) throws IOException {
    String pomPath = "/META-INF/maven/my.package.name/myApp/pom.xml";
    try (InputStream pomStream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream(pomPath)) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pomStream));
        return "";
    }
}
```